# get actual column width

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am building a DataGridView table programmatically and placing it within a GroupBox on a form.

I insert the data, then resize the columns automatically to fit the data. I then want to resize the groupbox to the size of the DataGridView. For each column and row, I get their respective width and height, which technically should be accurate, and update the panel and overall DataGridView sizes.

The **problem** is that Column.Width always returns 100 pixels regardless of its actual size (see screenshot: actual column width is around 30px, not 100). If I manually enter width = 90 pixels, the resizing is quite accurate!

```
matrix = new DataGridView();
//modify behaviour
matrix.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
matrix.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
matrix.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
matrix.RowHeadersVisible = false;
matrix.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
//modify positioning
matrix.Location = new Point(10, 20);
//matrix.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)(AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
matrix.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
//set the size of the matrix
matrix.ColumnCount = col;
matrix.RowCount = row;


//Data now inserted...
matrix.AutoResizeColumns(); //correctly resizes the columns

int height = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in matrix.Rows)
{
    height += row.Height;
}
height += matrix.ColumnHeadersHeight;

int width = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in matrix.Columns)
{
    width += col.Width;
    //PROBLEM: Width always  = 100 pixels.
}
width += matrix.RowHeadersWidth;
//width = 90; //override width manually
matrix.Size = new Size(width + 2, height + 2);
panel.Size = new Size(matrix.Width, matrix.Height);
```

[image: screenshot]

the panel is so large because width isn't 90px but 357 roughly, which is wrong!

**EDIT: PARTIAL FIX**
I have found a way to get the correct width of a cell:

```
DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].ContentBounds.Width
//ContentBounds = a rectangle with the exact dimensions of that cell
```

I can now set the DataGridView the correct size, but only if it's not Docked to Fill. Setting matrix.Dock = DockStyle.Fill prevents the resizing to occur correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem is:

1. DataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill prevented the DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns() method  from doing anything.
2. Rectangle rect = matrix.Rows[0].Cells[0].ContentBounds getting the dimensions of the rectangle containing the cell values didn't update after AutoResizeColumns()
3. I tried setting the columns manually, but as **heq** suggested, the AutoSizeColumnsMode must be set to None in order to be able to modify the width.
4. I adjusted the width of each column manually, to be 10px for each character inside the cell

Final Solution

```
/* Create the DataGridView */
matrix = new DataGridView();
//modify behaviour
matrix.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
// matrix.columnhea
matrix.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
matrix.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
matrix.RowHeadersVisible = false;
matrix.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
matrix.ReadOnly = true;
//modify positioning
matrix.Location = new Point(10, 20);
//matrix.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
matrix.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)(AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
//set the size of the matrix
matrix.ColumnCount = cols;
matrix.RowCount = rows;

panel.Controls.Add(matrix);

/* Set the data contents (not shown) */
...

/* Adjust the width of columns */
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) 
{
  int largest = 0; //largest number of characters in cell
  for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) 
  {
      int len = matrix.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value.ToString().Length;
      if (len > largest)
      {
          largest = len;
      }
  }
  matrix.Columns[c].Width = largest * 10;
  width += largest * 10;
}

/* Get height of table */
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in matrix.Rows)
{
    height += row.Height;
}

/* Set the DataGridView Size and Parent Panel size */
//Note: first set the parent panel width, the table is anchored to all of its edges
// as such table wont resize correctly if the panel isn't up to size first
panel.Size = new Size(width + 20, height + 30);
matrix.Size = new Size(width + 3, height + 3); //is it 1px per row and col?

/* Parent Panel settings kept to default, no modifications */
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is because you're autosizing your columns in row:

```
matrix.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

try to change it to:

```
matrix.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
```

Comment: If I changed it to none, then calling matrix.AutoResizeColumns(); doesn't fit the cell size to the cell content dimensions (the cells do stay at 100px). Could it be that the column headers are forcing the grid at 100px although I don't set any values for the headers and have hidden them? EDIT: i have shown the headers and these get resized correctly when AutoResizeColumns() is called. It seems that the Width property isn't updated when AutoResizeColumns is called...

Comment: Unfortunately I have no Visual Studio right now to try your code, but here is an article that might help you with sizing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Also as far as I remember it's possible to call something like `matrix.AutoResizeRows(
        DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders)` that might be useful

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have solved one issue for the time being (about to edit my post), but now it seems something else is preventing the correct resizing.

Comment: What about the `ColumnAdded` event: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0e38ba50-767e-4668-9d71-7e0083b768cf/datagridview-default-column-width?forum=winforms